# how do you write text on the status line with the filename, row and col number with vimscript?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to programmatically write on the bar below vim windows? I'm referring to the bar which displays the filename, cursor row + column, and the percentage of the document above the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called the status line.

You can get more information by typing `:help statusline`.

This is the one I used which includes line and column at the bottom right.

```
set statusline=%f%m%r%h\ [%L]\ [%{&ff}]\ %y%=[%p%%]\ [line:%05l,col:%02v]   
                │ │ │ │    │       │      │    │           │       │  
                │ │ │ │    │       │      │    │           │       └─ column number  
                │ │ │ │    │       │      │    │           └─── line number  
                │ │ │ │    │       │      │    └── percentage in file  
                │ │ │ │    │       │      └── file type  
                │ │ │ │    │       └── file format (dos/unix)  
                │ │ │ │    └── total number of line in file  
                │ │ │ └── help flag  
                │ │ └── read only flag  
                │ └── modified flag : [+] if modified, [-] if not modifiable  
                └── relative`
```

The rendering is not ideal but the options, which are starting with the `%`sign, are described from left to right as you go down. They are all described in help.

This is a pretty static configuration, if you are willing to use a vim-plugin, there are some like [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) that provides more advanced features like git integration.

Answer (score 2):

The information in that bar is set in the option `statusline`.  You can set this from within a script by using `let &statusline =` just as you would any other vim option.

See `:help statusline` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on this problem.

I set `laststatus` to turn off the "dedicated" status line and just use the command line area for the status (using `rulerformat` instead of `statusline`) if there's only one window.

```
set laststatus=1
set statusline=%F\ %(%w%h%r%m%)%=%2v:%4l/%4L\ 0x%02B
set rulerformat=%25(%w%h%r%<%m%=%2v:%4l/%4L\ 0x%02B%)
```

The status line displays the filename (with path) then a space and puts optional indicators for `[Preview]`, `[help]`, `[RO]`, and `[+]` (if the file is modified) depending on the file status.  The single-window version leaves out the filename.  In both, I then pad with spaces so the rest is right-justified, put two characters for the cursor column, then list the line number and total number of lines then the hex ASCII code for the character under the cursor.

There are a bunch of interesting examples in the help file, as others have said, check out `:help statusline`.